# SQL assign the value to the column based on value in the first column

Tags: sql

I am working with a dataframe that has 2 columns. Name and Type. I want to write a sql query that would check the values in the column "name" and based on the result will assign the value "direct" or "inderect" to the column "type"

`` sum(CASE when `Name` LIKE '%| R |%'
then `type` =  'Indirect'
    else `type` = 'Direct'
    end
 ) ``

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Please mention which Database you are using.

Comment: what error do you get? also share sample of your data and the output your require

Comment: I am working with DOMO platform. I actually don't need SUM. ```CASE when `Name` LIKE '%| R |%'
    
then 'Type' = 'Indirect';
    
else 'Type' = 'Direct'
    
end
 ``` And the error is: " Invalid Formula : This calculation contained a syntax error."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you need an update statement instead of a single case statement -

```
UPDATE YOUR_TAB
SET `type` = CASE WHEN `Name` LIKE '%| R |%' THEN 'Indirect'
                  ELSE 'Direct'
             END
-- WHERE CLAUSE IF NEEDED.
```